# Recycler View (Xamarin Android )

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin.android

I writing app for Android using Xamarin.

I try to make recycler view.

Here is my json  : http://pastebin.com/rL214a2T

I have classes like this:

```
 public class Billing
{
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
    public string address_1 { get; set; }
    public string address_2 { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string postcode { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
}

public class Shipping
{
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
    public string address_1 { get; set; }
    public string address_2 { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string postcode { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int parent_id { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string order_key { get; set; }
    public int number { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
    public bool prices_include_tax { get; set; }
    public string date_created { get; set; }
    public string date_modified { get; set; }
    public int customer_id { get; set; }
    public string discount_total { get; set; }
    public string discount_tax { get; set; }
    public string shipping_total { get; set; }
    public string shipping_tax { get; set; }
    public string cart_tax { get; set; }
    public string total { get; set; }
    public string total_tax { get; set; }
    //public List<Billing> billing { get; set; }
    public Billing billing { get; set; }
    public Shipping shipping { get; set; }
    public string payment_method { get; set; }
    public string payment_method_title { get; set; }
    public string transaction_id { get; set; }
    public string customer_ip_address { get; set; }
    public string customer_user_agent { get; set; }
    public string created_via { get; set; }
    public string customer_note { get; set; }
    public string date_completed { get; set; }
    public string date_paid { get; set; }
    public string cart_hash { get; set; }
    public List<object> line_items { get; set; }
    public List<object> tax_lines { get; set; }
    public List<object> shipping_lines { get; set; }
    public List<object> fee_lines { get; set; }
    public List<object> coupon_lines { get; set; }
    public List<object> refunds { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
}
```

I writing class like this:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ModernHttpClient;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace StarWars.Api.Repository
{
    public class MoviesRepository
    {
        public async Task<RootObject> GetAllFilms()
        {
            var httpClient = GetHttpClient();

            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(ServiceEndPoints.StartWarsApiBaseUri).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = response.Content;

                string jsonString = await content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);


                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
            }
            return new RootObject();
        }

        private HttpClient GetHttpClient()
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler())
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(ServiceEndPoints.StartWarsApiBaseUri)
            };


            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            return httpClient;
        }
    }

    public class ServiceEndPoints
    {
        public static readonly string StartWarsApiBaseUri = "http://api.simplegames.com.ua/index.php/?wc_orders=processing_orders";
       // public static readonly string GetFilmsUri = "films";
    }
}
```

But when I try to launch app I have this error

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'StarWars.Api.Repository.RootObject' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
```

As I understood I need to set

How I can fix it?

**UPDATE**

Using Resharper I remake code like this

```
 public async Task<List<RootObject>> GetAllFilms()
    {
        var httpClient = GetHttpClient();

        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(ServiceEndPoints.StartWarsApiBaseUri).ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = response.Content;

            string jsonString = await content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);


            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(jsonString);
        }
        return new List<RootObject>();
    }

    private HttpClient GetHttpClient()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler())
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(ServiceEndPoints.StartWarsApiBaseUri)
        };


        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        return httpClient;
    }
}

public class ServiceEndPoints
{
    public static readonly string StartWarsApiBaseUri = "http://api.simplegames.com.ua/index.php/?wc_orders=processing_orders";
   // public static readonly string GetFilmsUri = "films";
}
```

}

But i have error in my MainActivity in this row `var moviesAdapter = new MovieAdapter(films.results)`

Here is error

Error   CS1061  'List' does not contain a definition for 'results' and no extension method 'results' accepting a first argument of type 'List' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Can you share also your json?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/rL214a2T @mww

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need change your model classes, If you don't know how should be look your model classes you can use tool like [json2sharp](http://json2csharp.com/). You can't deserialize `JSON` using your classes. Use this classes instead your.

```
public class Billing
{
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
    public string address_1 { get; set; }
    public string address_2 { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string postcode { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
}

public class Shipping
{
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
    public string address_1 { get; set; }
    public string address_2 { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string postcode { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
}

public class LineItem
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string sku { get; set; }
    public int product_id { get; set; }
    public int variation_id { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public string tax_class { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
    public string subtotal { get; set; }
    public string subtotal_tax { get; set; }
    public string total { get; set; }
    public string total_tax { get; set; }
    public List<object> taxes { get; set; }
    public List<object> meta { get; set; }
}

public class ShippingLine
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string method_title { get; set; }
    public string method_id { get; set; }
    public string total { get; set; }
    public string total_tax { get; set; }
    public List<object> taxes { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int parent_id { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string order_key { get; set; }
    public int number { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
    public bool prices_include_tax { get; set; }
    public string date_created { get; set; }
    public string date_modified { get; set; }
    public int customer_id { get; set; }
    public string discount_total { get; set; }
    public string discount_tax { get; set; }
    public string shipping_total { get; set; }
    public string shipping_tax { get; set; }
    public string cart_tax { get; set; }
    public string total { get; set; }
    public string total_tax { get; set; }
    public Billing billing { get; set; }
    public Shipping shipping { get; set; }
    public string payment_method { get; set; }
    public string payment_method_title { get; set; }
    public string transaction_id { get; set; }
    public string customer_ip_address { get; set; }
    public string customer_user_agent { get; set; }
    public string created_via { get; set; }
    public string customer_note { get; set; }
    public string date_completed { get; set; }
    public string date_paid { get; set; }
    public string cart_hash { get; set; }
    public List<LineItem> line_items { get; set; }
    public List<object> tax_lines { get; set; }
    public List<ShippingLine> shipping_lines { get; set; }
    public List<object> fee_lines { get; set; }
    public List<object> coupon_lines { get; set; }
    public List<object> refunds { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: For current response there is no data for tax_lines , fee_lines , coupon_lines , refunds  but it would be better you create a json with all possible data and the use  http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Thank's dude.  It helps